# ActiveRecord #includes, with condition, but load all relations, not just those matching condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, relation

I have ActiveRecord models Parent and Kid.  Parents have many Kids.

I have a Parent whose name is Dad, with 3 Kids, whose names are Abel, Bobby, and Cain.  I want to find the Parent based on the name of only 1 of the Kids.

```
parent = Parent.includes(:kids).
  find_by(kids: { name: 'Bobby' })
```

The above query provides me the Parent I want, but `parent.kids` only includes Bobby.  I want Abel and Cain to be included in `parent.kids` as well, just like if I did:

```
Parent.find_by(name: 'Dad').kids
```

I could do:

```
Parent.includes(:kids).
  find_by(kids: { name: 'Bobby' }).
  tap { |parent| parent&.kids.reload }
```

But is there not a “better” way of fetching the rest of the kids?  For instance, is there a way I could load all the kids of the parent while querying for the parent (via one SQL statement)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making the `Parent.includes(:kids).find_by(kids: { name: 'Bobby' }` a subquery

```
Parent.includes(:kids).where(id: Parent.includes(:kids).find_by(kids: { name: 'Bobby' })
```

Answer (score 2):

You want an `INNER JOIN`:

```
parents = Parent.joins(:kids).where(kids: { name: 'Bobby' })
```

This will only include rows from parents with a match in the kids table. You can apply it as a subquery to avoid removing the rest of the joined rows:

```
parents = Parent.where(
            id: Parent.joins(:kids).where(kids: { name: 'Bobby' })
          ).includes(:kids)
```